# Validator for XPages textarea control, only when a certain button is pressed

Tags: validation, jsf, xpages

I have setup a validator for an inputfield:

```
<xp:inputTextarea id="inpRelPresentation"
    value="#{matterBean.matter.busRelations}"
    validator="#{matterValidators.valBusinessRelation}">    
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired>
            <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:xptI18NBean.getValue("matter.msg_valid_business_relation")}]]></xp:this.message>
        </xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ( submittedBy('btnSendToCommitee'))}]]></xp:this.required>
</xp:inputTextarea>
```

The required property is checked when I click a button with ID btnSendToCommittee.

When I click other buttons like Save the validator is called.

```
public void valBusinessRelation(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println("start valBusinessRelation");
        if (value == null || StringUtil.isEmpty((String) value)) {
            System.out.println("do a return");
            return;
        }
        String trimmed = ((String) value).trim();
        if (trimmed.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","").equals("")){
            System.out.println("empty after trimming etc, throw validator exception");
            String msgTxt = langBean.getValue("matter.msg_valid_business_relation");
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(msgTxt, msgTxt);
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
```

I would also like to add the condition that this validator is called ONLY when the btnSendToCommittee is pressed. I have no idea how to do this because the submittedBy('btnSendToCommitee') check is ssjs and call to the valBusinessRelation() method is EL.

I did not find any complete examples how to call a validator by validator-id described here:
http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=764

Answer (score 1):

I've added java code needed to do submittedBy-check in Java in my original blogpost:
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/03/xpages-making-validation-behave.html

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
public static String getParameter( String name ) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = resolveVariable( "param", Map.class );
    return parameters.get( name );
}

@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
public static UIComponent getChildComponent( UIComponent component, String id ) {
    if( id.equals( component.getId() ) ) {
        return component;
    }

    Iterator<UIComponent> children = component.getFacetsAndChildren();
    while( children.hasNext() ) {
        UIComponent child = children.next();
        UIComponent found = getChildComponent( child, id );
        if( found != null ) {
            return found;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static <T> T resolveVariable( String name, Class<T> typeClass ) {
    Object variable = ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable( FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), name );
    return variable == null ? null : typeClass.cast( variable );
}

public static UIComponent getComponent( String id ) {
    return getChildComponent( (UIViewRootEx)      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot(), id );
}

public static boolean wasSubmittedByComponentId( String componentId ) {
    if( componentId == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    String eventHandlerClientId = getParameter( "$$xspsubmitid" );
    if( eventHandlerClientId == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Extract the component id for the event handler
    String eventHandlerComponentId = eventHandlerClientId.replaceFirst( "^.*\\:(.*)$", "$1" );
    UIComponent eventHandler = getComponent( eventHandlerComponentId );
    if( eventHandler == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Fetch the component the event handler belongs to
    UIComponent submissionComponent = eventHandler.getParent();
    if( submissionComponent == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    return ( componentId.equals( submissionComponent.getId() ) );
}
```

The code was copy/pasted from different Java classes. Let me know if there is anything missing :)